# Pytest - чем заменить input или в чём отличие значения из input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, тестирование, pytest

Изучаю тестирование функций (через pytest).

Есть словарь с которым работает функция.

Ниже сама функция которую пытаюсь протестировать.

```
def get_doc_owner_name(numbers):
    user_doc_number = numbers # input('Введите номер документа - ') 
    print()
    doc_exist = check_document_existance(user_doc_number)
    if doc_exist:
        for current_document in documents:
            doc_number = current_document['number']
            if doc_number == user_doc_number:
                # return current_document['name']
                return "Code: 200"
```

Ниже тестирование

```
numbers = [
  '2207 876234', # Истинное значение. Всё остальное варианты тестирования.
  '22O7 876234',
  ...
  '220787623',
  ''
]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("number", numbers)
def test_get_doc_owner_name(number):
  assert get_doc_owner_name(number) == 'Code: 200'
```

Если миновать тест и в функцию `get_doc_owner_name()` значение `numbers[0]` ввести через `input`,
`return` срабатывает.
Так же `return` срабатывает если значение задать как аргумент `get_doc_owner_name('2207 876234')`

При попытке тестирования через `@pytest.mark.parametrize("number", numbers)` ни одно значение из `numbers`  не проходит

```
testing.py:19 (test_get_doc_owner_name[22O7 876234])
None != Code: 200

Expected :Code: 200
Actual   :None
```

В чём отличие значения из input от строки заданной как значение аргумента?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> В чём отличие значения из input от строки заданной как значение аргумента?

Примерно во всем.

- `input()` - это запрос ввода от пользователя через консоль.
- Аргумент функции сам по себе ничего не запрашивает, но его наличие подразумевает, что при вызове функции в нее должен быть передан параметр.

  Фактически значение параметра может быть получено откуда угодно - не только с консоли, но и например из файла, из базы, из другой функции.

  Если вы в функцию вшиваете `input()`, а не используете параметр, то вы ограничиваете возможность получения значения только с консоли. В том числе и при тестировании функции вам придется подменять функцию `input()`, чтобы она не ждала ввода пользователя, а возвращала тестовые данные. При передаче значений в функцию через параметр тестирование становится более простым.

Чтобы функция у вас работала так же как и раньше, то нужно при ее вызове передать ей результат input-а:

```
user_doc_number = input('Введите номер документа - ')
print(get_doc_owner_name(user_doc_number))
```

Дальше, при тестировании если у вас "истинное" значение только одно, то со всеми остальными значениями тест будет валиться, т.к. не будет выполняться условие `get_doc_owner_name(number) == 'Code: 200'`. Чтобы тест работал, нужно в него еще передать ожидаемый результат (значение, которое должна вернуть тестируемая функция при заданном входном значении):

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("number, result", [
  ('2207 876234', 'Code: 200'), # Истинное значение. Всё остальное варианты тестирования.
  ('22O7 876234', None),  # На некорректных значениях функция get_doc_owner_name возвращает None (т.к. нет return после выхода из цикла)
  ...
  ('220787623', None),
  ('', None)
])
def test_get_doc_owner_name(number, result):
  assert get_doc_owner_name(number) == result
```

- так тест будет проверять, что при значении `'2207 876234'` функция возвращает `'Code: 200'`, а при других значениях возвращает `None`.

Comment: спасибо. 
Вопрос закрыт. )